# Bundler and Rbenv Gem Path

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems, bundler, rbenv

I am using Bundler and Rbenv, with everything working fine. However if I use:

```
$ bundle show example
```

The path returned seems odd as it contains a reference to ruby 1.9.1:

```
/Users/me/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/fog-1.15.0
```

Is this normal? Why is `1.9.1` in the path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1.9.1` is compatibility level for all `1.9.x` rubies, it was the same for `1.9.1` and `1.9.2`

Answer (score -1):

probably ruby-gems version 1.9.1 within ruby 1.9.3

```
bundle exec ruby -v
bundle exec gem -v
```

Comment: ruby is at 1.9.3p392 and gem is at 1.8.23